# Compiler for SASS

Tags: css, build, sass

I just started using SASS in my project and I want a script to compile them and convert them to CSS files. Im planning to run this script only when I build.

I installed SASS in my system and SASS --watch doesn't seem to be the right approach here; as I told, I want a script that runs only when I build. I used to have one such script for LESS compiling, but couldn't find any for SASS.

Does anyone know of any such scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html), just run sass from the command line as part of your build script. An example for a one time use on a single file:

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

link:

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can just do `sass --update` for a one-time compile from Sass to CSS. This will use whatever settings already exist in `config.rb`.